# Using `RangeFull` syntax with strings and `Borrow`

Tags: indexing, rust

I'm working on a `pandas`-like library for Rust, and one of the features I'd like to support is psuedo-slicing of indices (and series/frames later on) using the Rust range syntax (e.g. `0..=5`, `..7`, `4..`, `..`, etc) using `RangeBounds`.

In addition, I'd like to support using references to the data contained in the index as bounds for the range, not just integers. So if an index has `["dog", "cat", "bird", "sheep"]`, I'd like to support a lookup of `.loc_range(&"dog"..=&"bird")` to return the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd items, for instance.

I've gotten to the point where primitive `Copy` types that I support as labels work perfectly, but I'm stuck on `String`. Not only does it feel weird to use `"str"` instead of `&"str"` (see code example below, comparing the `char` and the `String` usages, and probably worth a new SO question), but the naive `..` call on the `String` version fails to compile at all! Instead, I have to specify the type parameters, as shown on the last line of code.

If this was an internal call, I'd just make the change and continue on. But I intend for this to be a user-facing function, and I'd hate to have users need to specify the type arguments for this edge case. Is there a way around this? More specifically, I'm looking to be able to not have to specify type vars for the `TestIndex<String>::loc_range(..)` case.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::ops::RangeBounds;

pub trait TestLabel: Debug + Clone + Sized + PartialEq +
                     Eq + Hash + PartialOrd + Ord {}

impl TestLabel for char {}
impl TestLabel for String {}

pub struct TestIndex<L: TestLabel>(Vec<L>);

impl<L: TestLabel> TestIndex<L> {
    pub fn loc_range<'a, R, Q: 'a>(&self, range: R) -> Option<Vec<usize>>
    where
        R: RangeBounds<&'a Q>,
        L: Borrow<Q>,
        Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized,
    {
        // Actual code uses `IndexSet` and does a set lookup,
        // hence the use of `Borrow`.
        // This is just dummy code to get a minimum working example.
        None
    }

    pub fn test() {
        let i = TestIndex(vec!['a', 'b', 'c']);

        // OK!
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range(&'a'..&'c'));
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range(..&'c'));
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range(&'a'..));
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range(..));

        let i = TestIndex(vec![
            String::from("a"),
            String::from("b"),
            String::from("c"),
        ]);

        // Strange that no '&' is needed, but compiles
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range("a".."c"));
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range(.."c"));
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range("a"..));

        // ERROR E0283
        // cannot resolve `std::string::String: std::borrow::Borrow<_>`
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range(..));

        // Compiles, but feels very unergonomic!
        println!("{:?}", i.loc_range::<_, str>(..));
    }
}
```

NOTE: I posted this question on the Rust Discord, but also wanted to get some opinions and insights here on SO, especially since I can provide more context and background for the use case I have!

Comment: FWIW, I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with your now-deleted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to make your own trait

Like so: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f08dba83840f06bc69ffa203bf9838a4

(note: I didn't fill out all of the required implementations, you will need an implementation of `LocRange<_>` for each of the range types)
You can minimize the boiler-plate by going back through a function like

```
pub fn generic_loc_range_impl<'a, R, L, Q: 'a>(test_index: &TestIndex<L>, range: R) -> Option<Vec<usize>>
    where
        R: RangeBounds<&'a Q>,
        L: Borrow<Q> + TestLabel,
        Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized,
{
    ...
}
```

In each of the implementations, these implementations are just to remove the unnecessary type parameter for `RangeFull` which causes the inference failure.
In the `RangeFull` impl you can call it like `generic_loc_range_impl::<RangeFull, L, L>(self, ..)`

Comment: This makes sense now, `RangeFull` doesn't take type args, so the helper trait abstracts over the different kinds of range types. Thank you!